# Adding labels and descriptive label to D3.js donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, donut-chart

I'm using the following d3.js donut chart: [jsfiddel](http://fiddle.jshell.net/q7SJ4)

What I would like to do is extend this example so that:

1. Each coloured section needs a text label
2. I want to colour in the centre of the donut, and add some text to the centre of the donut
3. I need to be able to style each path based on it's class, so how can I apply a class?

Any help appreciated, many of the samples for d3.js are hosted on a site which is currently down .

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've found a sample which pretty much covers everything I need: http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9